# Compare a list of IDs to a master list, and either create or delete master list records based on found/not found

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have a list of IDs: `List<Integer> updatedIds`.

I have a master list (say, taken from the DB): `List<Records> masterList`.

I want to do the following:

1. For each ID in `updatedIds`, check if it's in `masterList`. If not, add the record to the `masterList`.
2. For each Record in `masterList`, check if it's in `updatedIds`. If not, it is obsolete, so remove it from `masterList.`

The straightforward code for this is as follows:

```
for (Integer updId : updatedIds) {
    boolean hasMapping = false;
    for (Record rec : masterList) {
        if (rec.getId() == updId) { hasMapping = true; break; }
    }
    if (!hasMapping) {
        //TODO add updId to masterList
    }
}
for (Record rec : masterList) {
    boolean isObsolete = true;
    for (Integer updId : updatedIds) {
        if (rec.getId() == updId) { isObsolete = false; break; }
    }
    if (isObsolete) {
        //TODO remove rec from masterList
    }
}
```

The first loop takes care of requirement 1, the second takes care of requirement 2. It looks very inefficient, and I think I may be using the wrong data structure for this kind of task.

Is there a more efficient way of implementing the algorithm above?

Comment: for the second loop you can use _HashMap.get(updatedId)_ this would be better

Comment: why use a map? what would be the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you sort both lists (e.g. using Collections.sort), the updatedIDs in natural order and the masterList ordered by ID, you can set up a single loop to go through both of them. You could possibly *retrieve* the records in sorted order, if they come from a DB, and skip that step.

```
Collections.sort(masterList, myComparator);
Collections.sort(updatedIDs);

Iterator m_it = masterList.iterator();
Iterator u_it = updatedIDs.iterator();

// * Some code here to deal with the possibility that either list is empty

Record rec    = m_it.next();
int    u      = u_it.next();
bool   done   = false;

while (! done) {
  if (rec.getID() < u) {
    // rec's ID was missing from updatedIDs
    m_it.remove();

    if (m_it.hasNext()) {
      rec = m_it.next();
    } else {
      done = true;
      // * add u and all subsequent updated IDs to master list
    }
  } else if (rec.getID() > u) {
    // u is new - doesn't occur in masterList
    // * add u to masterList (or probably to a separate list that you
    //   later append to masterList)

    if (u_it.hasNext()) {
      u = u_it.next();
    } else {
      done = true;
      // * remove rec and all remaining records from the master list
    }
  } else {
    // rec's ID matches u: proceed to next pair of items
    bool m_nx = m_it.hasNext(), u_nx = u_it.hasNext();
    if (m_nx && u_nx) {
      rec = m_it.next();
      u = u_it.next();
    } else if ((! m_nx) && (! u_nx)) {
      done = true;
    } else if (m_nx && (! u_nx)) {
      done = true;
      // * remove all subsequent records from the master list
    } else if ((! m_nx) && u_nx) {
      done = true;
      // * add all subsequent integers in updatedIDs to the master list
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `HashSet`. that will give you a constant time look up. however, each item in your set should be unique. then you can use that number as hashcode as well and you have `O(1)` lookup whereas in List you have `O(n)` lookup time.

Comment: Did you mean: use HashSet<Integer> for the second loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can `HashMap<Integer,Records>` instead of `List<Records>`. Where you will get constant look up `O(1)`.
HashMap -> Integer - id and Records - corresponding record.